# ASPNetCore WebApi Route parameter name matching

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, routes, asp.net-core

I generated my controller from my swagger specification (used: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#aspnet-5-web-api). Unfortunately, the generator generates something like:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("/bs/foo/{my_bar}")]
[SwaggerOperation("BsFooMyBarPost")]
public void BsFooMyBarPost([FromRoute]string myBar, [FromBody]MyDto dto)
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

That results in `myBar` being `null`. If I change `{my_bar}` to `{myBar}` everything is working as expected. I'm using asp.net core rc2.

Is it possible to adjust the parameter name matching rules?

Comment: If it works when you change the name then why not just use it with the name changed.

Comment: Because it is generated code...

Comment: And there is no way to get the generated code to generate the correct route parameter to matching method parameter? I'd start there.

Comment: Maybe, but I haven't found something. I looked up both. But if there would be another solution, I'd like to know how to change the router behavior :)